# Error (Azure Key Vault) is configured for use by Azure Active Directory users only

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

**Full Error:**
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.KeyVaultReferenceException: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: AADSTS9002332: Application 'cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093'(Azure Key Vault) is configured for use by Azure Active Directory users only. Please do not use the /consumers endpoint to serve this request.
Trace ID: a4b9a7c9-8eb4-48ff-8871-8a63d69b1400
(Azure Key Vault) is configured for use by Azure Active Directory users only. Please do not use the /consumers endpoint to serve this request.

---

I am walking through the example at this Microsoft Doc page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=powershell%2Ccore3x

No errors on build, but when I launch the site on localhost, I get the above error.

**Here is the code in the Program.cs file:**

```
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var settings = config.Build();

                config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                {
                    options.Connect(settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"])
                            .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                            {
                                kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                            });
                });
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
        // See: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/71592
```

Can anyone tell me what to try next?

See: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/71592

Comment: COuld you please provide your code?

Comment: @JimXu :  Note, I just added all the code.  Please note, I am just trying to follow the tutorial at the link in the description.  Most of the work is in the configuration of Azure Key Vault, Azure CLI and Azure App Config.

Comment: Thanks @JimXu... This answer was helpful.  To make it run locally, I had to include the Azure Tenant in my Visual Studio 2019 Environment Variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to access Azure key vault, please refer to the following steps

1. Create service principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "http://mySP" --sdk-auth
```

2. Set access policy in azure keyvault

```
az keyvault set-policy -n <your-unique-keyvault-name> --spn <clientId-of-your-service-principal> --secret-permissions delete get list set --key-permissions create decrypt delete encrypt get list unwrapKey wrapKey --secret-permissions backup delete get list purge recover restore set
```

3. Code

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
             Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
             {
                 var settings = config.Build();

                 config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                 {
                     options.Connect(settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"])
                             .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                             {
                                 var cert = new ClientSecretCredential("<tenant id>", "client id", "client secret");
                                 kv.SetCredential(cert);
                             });
                 });
             })
             .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

[image]

Besides, if you run the application with VS 2019, you can use the extension `Azure Service Authentication`. But you need to use one work account in the tenant to login and configure right access policy for the account in the key vault. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication)

Comment: Your answer is not a solution for the case when Azure Active Directory is used to manage access to a Key Vault

Comment: Your answer is not a solution for the case when Azure Active Directory is used to manage access to a Key Vault